# AngularJS objects should work independently

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have 2 array objects both initialized with $http response but when I try to add(push) in one array, it gets added into both.

I tried below code:

**Controller:**

```
myApp.controller("abc", function($scope, lastday_data){
    $scope.objectiveData = [];
    $scope.doneData = [];

    // call service & get data from server
    lastday_data.getData().then(function(success){
        $scope.objectiveData = success;
        $scope.doneData = success;
        $scope.$digest();  // *---> $digest() used*
    },function(error){
        $scope.objectiveData = null;
        $scope.doneData = null;
    });

    // add task done
    $scope.addTaskDone = function() {
        var p = {"id": 101, "name": "testadd", "check": true};
        $scope.doneData.push(p);
        $scope.textDone = "";
    }
});
```

**Service:**   -- get data from the server

```
myApp.service("lastday_data", function($http){
    this.getData = function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost/task/index.php/v1/example/users'
            }).then(function (response) {
                if(response.status)
                    resolve(response.data);
                else
                    reject();
            },function (error) {
                reject();
            });
        });
    }
});
```

**Problem:** when I try to call controller's `addTaskDone()` method, this method add one object in `doneData` array but this object get added in `objectiveData` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The problem

Both `$scope.objectiveData` and `$scope.doneData` are referencing the same variable `success`, so if you change one, the other one is changed too.

#### Solution

Make `$scope.objectiveData` and `$scope.doneData` reference independent variables by getting independent copies of `success`. You can use for this

*Plain JavaScript*

- [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice): `$scope.doneData = success.slice();`
- [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat): `$scope.doneData = [].concat(success);`
- [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from): `$scope.doneData = Array.from(success);`
- [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign): `$scope.doneData = Object.assign([], success);`

*AngularJS builtin functions*

- [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy): `$scope.doneData = angular.copy(success);`
- [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend): `$scope.doneData = angular.extend([], success);`
- [angular.merge](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge) <sup>(Deprecated since 1.6.5, see [known issues](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge#known-issues))</sup>: `$scope.doneData = angular.merge([], success);`

*Other tricks*

- [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)/[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) [**<sup>[1]</sup>**](http://www.competa.com/blog/make-deep-copy-javascript-array-objects-remove-reference/):

`$scope.doneData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(success));`

So **instead of**

```
$scope.objectiveData = success;
$scope.doneData = success;
```

**Do** (or any other of the previous alternatives)

```
$scope.objectiveData = success.slice(); // get a copy of success
$scope.doneData = success.slice(); // get a copy of success
```

Comment: thanks for this, I didn't know about `Array.from`.  So much new es6 to learn, so little time.

Answer (score 3):

Basically the problem is `objectiveData` & `doneData` $scope variables are holding same memory location. So changing any of the value would make changes in all of three value `success`, `objectiveData` and `doneData`.

So basically you should make sure that while assigning a one variable with multiple values, create a clone of that `success` variable and keep then assign that variable to desired variable.

In angularjs there is `angular.copy` method exists, which will help you to create clone of an object with new memory location. That will ensure that the new variable will point to different memory location.

**Controller:**

```
$scope.objectiveData = angular.copy(success);
$scope.doneData = angular.copy(success);
```

---

**Bonus:** It clearly seems that you have wrong implementation of service, where you're creating an promise explicitly that's the reason why you had to call `$digest` inside your `.then` success callback. It means that you're creating an cases where you have to run digest cycle manually since code will be running outside angularjs context. Rather you should return the existing `$http` promise like below, and remove `$scope.$digest()` from you code which isn't needed at all.

**Service**

```
myApp.service("lastday_data", function($http) {
  this.getData = function() {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost/task/index.php/v1/example/users'
    }).then(function(response) {
      if (response.status)
        return response.data;
      else
        return $q.reject('Problem retrieving data');
    }, function(error) {
      return $q.reject(error);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It is the more *angular* way and also corrects the $digest issue.